# Ms Graph : How to Defer Commit of a file with the SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I would like to defer the file commit's when i use the SDK upload session.
This is possible with the API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

> {
> "item": {
> "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
> },
> "deferCommit": true
> }

But in the SDK : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp
I couldn't find the equivalent in DriveItemUploadableProperties object

```
public class DriveItemUploadableProperties
{        
    public DriveItemUploadableProperties();
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
   
    public long? FileSize { get; set; }
    
    public FileSystemInfo FileSystemInfo { get; set; }
   
    public string Name { get; set; }
   
    public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalData { get; set; }
    
    public string ODataType { get; set; }
}
```

How do i send the deferCommit flag and how do i send the completing flag ?

Edit 1 :

I've try :

```
 DriveItemUploadableProperties properties = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
        {
            ODataType = null,
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" },
                {"deferCommit", true}
            }
        };
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The `deferCommit` property isn't a member of the [driveItemUploadableProperties class](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/d25a1292fb64959ed9d7e9e923b3e4533f0a8ab1/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/DriveItemUploadableProperties.cs). This property should be set as part of the `AdditionalData` of DriveItemUploadableProperties. Please see documentation on [completing a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#completing-a-file) for details on how to explicitly complete the upload.

This might look something like this:

```
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" },
        {"deferCommit", true}
    },
```

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.

Comment: Thx, for the answer, could you show me a sample please? i've try to add DeferComit in the AdditionalData but it didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome - I've added a sample above

Comment: Sorry, i'have test it but it doesn't work, see my Edit 1. if i send all the file bytes, the file is automaticly commit, and not defer.